# [Xcode]How to count NSArray according to type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, uitableview

I would like to ask how could I count object type inside array. For example

this is my dataclass

```
+ (id)LocationWithID:(NSString *)UniqueID name:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address latitude:(float )latitude longitude:(float )longitude locationtype:(NSString *)locationtype country:(NSString *)country distance:(float )distance;
```

and this is my array

```
[array addObject:[dataclass LocationWithID:UniqueID name:name address:address latitude:latitude longitude:longitude locationtype:locationtype country:country distance:distance]];
```

and i would like to count how many country in this object. Normally we use 
[array count];
but this will count all the object in the array. Now in my case i want to count non-repeated object for example i got an array contain 3 United kingdom, 5 USA, 7 Japan, 3 China and the result i want is country type = 4.

I would like to create several section for Table View according to the country type. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to put objects with the same country in a separate array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (dataclass *location in array) {
    if (![dictionary objectForKey:location.country]) {
        [dictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:location.country];
    }
    [(NSMutableArray *)[dictionary objectForKey:location.country] addObject:location];
}
```

Now, not only you can get the number of different countries like this:

```
int countriesCount = [dictionary count];
```

But also, it is easy to populate each section of your table view with locations from the corresponding country.

You can retrieve all the locations for a specific country that has the name `countryName`, like this:

```
NSArray *locationsForCountry = [dictionary objectForKey:countryName];
```

You can also have the list of all the countries like this:

```
NSArray *countries = [[dictionary keyEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Comment: i received this warning when i insert that dictionary code  warning: Semantic Issue: Collection expression type 'dataclass *' may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'


[ScreenShot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2305062/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-04%20at%2000.07.02.png).

Comment: What is `agileLocation`? Is it a class? Why don't you use `dataClass`?

Comment: I retyped the code again and the warning goes away. I'll give it a try now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate each item in the array and for each item get the country and add it to an NSMutableSet. After enumeration, the size of the set is the number of unique countries.

There's probably a better way to do this if you're creating a table and you just want the table to have a section for each country, but I don't know it. I'd guess that it would be something like binding the appropriate properties in the table for creating sections to the right values in the array controller or on the array controller's elements.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray doesn't have this functionality itself, so, as others have pointed out, it'd be easiest to keep a separate tally of counts for each country. The best way to do this would be to create an NSCountedSet object and add the countries to that as you add your data objects to the array.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

To get the count for any country, you just call [set countForObject:country]. Simple!

Comment: Only simple if your objects implement methods for testing equality correctly.

Comment: Note that the country argument is an NSString. :)

Comment: Ah my bad - that's a lot of scrolling I would of had to have done to see that. Maybe some new lines and colon alignment would have saved me the red face.